# USB hub and upstream/downstream speeds

Tags: usb, usb-host, usb-hub

I am designing a USB hub that has a 2.0 upstream connection (pc is only 2.0). To one of the downstream ports I am connecting a Ethernet to USB IC capable of USB3.0 speed and Gb ethernet.

My question is...does it make sense to have a USB3.0 hub IC or a 2.0 will be more than enough ? Will I get any boost in performance with a 3.0 hub ic ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**No.**

The 2.0 upstream connection to your PC will be your bottleneck. Even with 3.0 hardware downstream, the devices will only be able to transfer data to the laptop at a 2.0 rate. Don't spend extra money or time implementing USB 3.0.